# transform.rotate in Blender 2.8

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, axis

The below script for blender 2.7x is not working with 2.80
How could I fix it? I got the message - "TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "axis" unrecognized".

```
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=wheel_rotation_angle , axis=(wheel_rotation_x_axis, wheel_rotation_y_axis, wheel_rotation_z_axis), constraint_axis=(False, True, True))
```

Comment: Use orient_axis instead of axis as the argument name. Check the ops documentation [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.transform.html).

Comment: "axis" has 3 floating values, however, "orient_axis" has 3x3 floating values.

Answer (score 2):

Select the object in the 3D window ; key in <kbd>r</kbd>,<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>30</kbd>    to rotate 30 deg about the x-axis ; Visit the info window to see and copy/paste the equivalent python code.

I forgot which is local and which is global, i.e. experiment with <kbd>r</kbd>,<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>30</kbd> or <kbd>r</kbd>,<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>30</kbd>

Note also the use of degrees with the keyboard, but radians in the script:
`bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=pi/6, orient_axis='Z',\ orient_type='LOCAL')` verified with Blender 2.8

We have left off the numerous optional arguments in this example